# Getting JSONP from Google Books API using jQuery .ajax and jQueryMobile example

Tags: web-services, jquery, jquery-mobile, google-api

Reading the Google Books API they have the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/getting_started#data-json) on how to use the REST API, and also they mention about using the API with a client [javascript](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/getting_started#data-json).

I am making a phonegap/JQueryMobile application, and I want to fetch data using ajax, and Google Books API but their API is hard for me to understand.

What I want to fetch is JSONP object using the $.ajax method.

Do you have any example code, that fetches data using Google Books API and using jQuery $.ajax that would work in a phonegap application.

Do I have excplicity to provide the callback method, or do I go for for this, is just to confusing...

In this code:

```
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
      function handleResponse(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i];
        // in production code, item.text should have the HTML entities escaped.
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.volumeInfo.title;
      }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry+potter&callback=handleResponse"></script>
  </body>
```

from Google Books API they say you can get JSONP data, but I just cant seem to grasp how to do this with jQUery $.ajax and using jsonp as type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to get you started, you can do this:

```
// Set the api variable
var googleAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry+potter";

// Make a ajax call to get the json data as response.
$.getJSON(googleAPI, function (response) {

    // In console, you can see the response objects
    console.log("JSON Data: " + response.items);

    // Loop through all the items one-by-one
    for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {

        // set the item from the response object
        var item = response.items[i];

        // Set the book title in the div
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.volumeInfo.title;
      }
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FXLjm/)

Comment: Hej thank you for your example. I have on question is confusing me so much lately trying to understand java script. You use a anonymous function, with a argument `response` how do you now what is going to be on added on that argument, I have mostly a java experience and this kind of style of calling method is so confusing to me. If I wanted to add a API key and a dynamic value depending on user input, what would you change in this code?

Comment: Actually, that anonymous function is a callback function that is executed if the request succeeds. The success callback is passed the returned data, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and parsed using the $.parseJSON() method. It is also passed the text status of the response. You can find more info about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: So I see the argument, is actually the data returned, it took me quite a while to finally grasp this concept, thank you for this. One question, what is the difference on you code from their example, they use a link with a callback method `src="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry+potter&callback=handleResponse"` for example you are not adding the callback at the end of the url as they do?

Comment: `&callback=handle‌​Response` is used to load a JSON data Object from another domain (with callback function) which here's the `handle‌​Response` function.